Read singlestore data from spark using python
I am totally new to spark and singlestore. I am trying to read data  from singlestore using spark,this is the code i have written -
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .appName("ReadFromSingleStore") \
   .config("spark.datasource.singlestore.host", "abcd1") \
   .config("spark.datasource.singlestore.port", 3306) \
   .config("spark.datasource.singlestore.user", "abcd2") \
   .config("spark.datasource.singlestore.password", "abcd3") \
   .config("spark.datasource.singlestore.database", "abcd4") \
   .getOrCreate()



# Read data from SingleStore table
sql = "select * from INV_DOI_CDL_VW order by INSERTED_DATE ASC, TRANSACTION_ID DESC limit 100"
df = spark.read.format("singlestore").option("query", sql).load()


results = df.collect()
for row in results:
   print(row)

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()

I also have the singlestore-spark-connector jar in my directory. when i am trying to run this code i am getting this error-
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
what am i doing wrong? this is my first time working with singlestore.

Did you provide the link to the Spark Connector when you launched Spark? For example:
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.singlestore:singlestore-spark-connector_2.12:4.1.6-spark-3.5.0

Check the GH repo for additional details. The documentation is also a good place to start.
